# Is Dragon Orb evil?

Tags: dragonlance

In *Dragons of the Winter Night*, a Dragon Orb is described as an artifact containing the essence of dragons (not specifying, good, or evil, or both). The danger of handling it, as Raistlin states, is due to lack of will or incompetence of a person attempting to gain control of the Orb.

In *Dragons Of the Highlord Skies*, the Dragon Orb contains essence of only evil (chromatic) dragons, and is not only sentient, but a malevolent scheming artifact, intent on subverting people and bringing their doom.

Is there a contradiction? Are there other sources confirming the alignment of a Dragon Orb? Not only novels, but possibly rulebooks?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dragonlance_artifacts#Dragon_Orbs - "*Tracy Hickman explains that, with time, the Dragon Orbs grew their own minds.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numerous times throughout the series, it is stated that the Dragon Orbs were created by members of all three robes, containing the essences of all dragons. This makes the orb neither good, nor evil. They do, however, have a strong will which can be imposed upon the user. This, along with their self preservation motivation, could make one appear evil.